# C check string's from a text file

Tags: c

I am new at c and I am writing a code that get a string from the user and compare it to a strings from the text file and my code is only working when I compare between two characters and when I compare between two strings it's not working If someone know how can I fix the problem it's will be verey helpful. the compare line is in the searchFile function. the text file is a csv file so insted compare the char to string I need to compare between what befor the , to the string_to_search. example for csv file at the end of the code

Example: string to search = 'c' work, string to search 'name' doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR_LEN 100

int searchFile(char* string_to_search, char* path);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* text_file = 0;
    int found = 0, choice = 0;
    char string_to_search[STR_LEN] = {0};
    if (!(fopen(argv[1], "r") == NULL)) //check if file exists
    {
        do 
        {
            printf("Please enter your choice:\n");
            printf("1 - Search a term in the document.\n");
            printf("2 - change a value in a specific place.\n");
            printf("3 - copy a value from one place to another\n");
            printf("4 - Exit\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            getchar();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    fgets(string_to_search, STR_LEN, stdin);
                    string_to_search[strcspn(string_to_search, "\n")] = 0;
                    found = searchFile(string_to_search, argv[1]); //found = where the string line
                    if (found != 0)
                        printf("Value was found in row %d\n", found);
                    else
                        printf("Value Wasn't Found\n");
            }
        }while(choice != 4);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("file does not exists\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int searchFile(char* string_to_search, char* path)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
    char ch = ' ';
    int i = 0, len = 0, count = 1;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    len = len - 2;
    char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    do //copying the chars to a string
    {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        string[i] = ch;
        i++;
    } while (ch != EOF);
    fclose(file);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == *string_to_search) //the compare
        {
            free(string);
            return count;
        }
        if (string[i] == '\n')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Example for a CSV file:

```
roee,itay,3,4
5,6,7,8
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

Comment: why arent you using strcmp?

Comment: because it's give me error, strcmp not work with chars only string's i think

Comment: You compare characters with `==` and strings with `strcmp()` ... period. (unless you roll your own loop to mimic what `strcmp()` does...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the following line:

```
if (string[i] == *string_to_search) //the compare
```

into

```
if (string[i] == string_to_search[i]) //the compare
```

The problem is that `*string_to_search` always refers to the first character of `string_to_search`. With the `[i]` you will get the nth character of the string as you have done it for the variable `string`. So as you noticed it works for a comparsion of two characters but not for two strings, because on a string you will always compare with the first character of `string_to_search`. For example if you want to compare `"aaa"` it will also work.

But as noted in the comment section you may also want to use `strcmp()` instead of the loop. There you will also have to pass `string_to_search` and not `*string_to_search`, because you want to pass the pointer to the string and not a single character.

Comment: but it's work every time that the first character is the same like the string in the file will be 'roee' and the string_to_search will be 'rsd'. and what I am looking for is that it will be compare between 'roee' to 'roee' and not only the first char

Comment: the file is a csv file

Comment: so I need to compare between the string_to_search and the string before the ,

Comment: @roee: Maybe you should edit your question and give us a example CSV file and an example input for `string_to_search`.

Comment: yea I did that know

Comment: @roee: In this case you will have to change how your loop works. First you should save your current position and then search for the next `,` character. If you have found that then you can compare the characters / or the string between with `string_to_search`.